# Android drag and drop TextView bug

Tags: android

I followed [this tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-implementing-drag-and-drop-functionality/) for drag and drop functionality and it works except for a strange bug.

Dragging textview A onto Textview B is suppose to:

1. hide textview A
2. pass a tag from textview A to textview B
3. redisplay the passed data on textview B

Passing the data from textview A to B works 100% of the time, but oddly, textview A does not go invisible 100% of the time. I dont know if its the way I'm physically dragging it over textview B or something. Any idea how I can make that more stable?

```
public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        //handle drag events
        switch (event.getAction()) {
           case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
            //handle the dragged view being dropped over a drop view

            View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
            //stop displaying the view where it was before it was dragged
            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            //view dragged item is being dropped on
            TextView dropTarget = (TextView) v;
            //view being dragged and dropped
            TextView dropped = (TextView) view;
            //update the text in the target view to reflect the data being dropped
            dropTarget.setText(dropped.getText());
            //make it bold to highlight the fact that an item has been dropped
            dropTarget.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
            //if an item has already been dropped here, there will be a tag
            Object tag = dropTarget.getTag();
            //if there is already an item here, set it back visible in its original place
            if(tag!=null)
            {
                //the tag is the view id already dropped here
                int existingID = (Integer)tag;
                //set the original view visible again
                findViewById(existingID).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            //set the tag in the target view to the ID of the view being dropped
            dropTarget.setTag(dropped.getId());
            // check choice
            checkChoice(dropped,dropTarget);
            break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Think I found the problem

```
if(tag!=null)
        {
            //the tag is the view id already dropped here
            int existingID = (Integer)tag;
            //set the original view visible again   
            //findViewById(existingID).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);   COMMENT THIS OUT
        }
```